# How to split string by new lines in JAVA?

Tags: java, split, inputstream

I want to split string by new lines in Java.I am using following regex -

```
str.split("\\r|\\n|\\r\\n");
```

But still it is not splitting string by new lines.
Input -

```
0 
0 
0 
0
```

Output = String [] array = {"0000"} instead I want = String [] array = {"0","0","0","0"}.
I have read various solutions on stack overflow but nothing works for me.

Code is -

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class Input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         String line;
         String text = "";
         try {
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                text = text + line; 
             }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


         String [] textarray = text.trim().split("[\\r\\n]+");

       for(int j=0;j<textarray.length;j++)
         System.out.println(textarray[j]);
//         System.out.print("");
//         for(int i=((textarray.length)-1);i>=0;i--){
//           long k = Long.valueOf(textarray[i]).longValue();
//           System.out.println(k);
////             double sqrt = Math.sqrt(k);
////             double value = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(sqrt));
////             System.out.println(value);
////             
////        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide example code that reproduces the problem. I tried your pattern against `String input = "0\n0\n0\n0";` and it works fine.

Comment: can you provide your code

Comment: yeah provided the code.

Comment: Your input to the `split()` method here is `"0000"`, so that is what you get afterwards too.

Comment: Can you also post the exact input of the user that is creating the problem?

Comment: It's not clear to me how a user would finish providing input with your code example. Does Ctrl-D trigger a null return value?

Comment: Also, surely, if you want an array of each line entered, and you have this code, instead of building up a string and splitting it, you could just build up an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `br.readLine()`, the newline characters are stripped from the end of the string. So if you type `0 + ENTER` four times, you are trying to split the string `"0000"`.

You would be better to read items in from stdin and store them in an expandable data structure, such as a `List<String>`. No need to split things if you've already read them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:
If you are reading the `inputstream`from the keyboard, the \n may not be put into the data correctly. In that case, you may want to choose a new sentinel value.

Original Answer:
I believe you need to create a sentinel value. So if `\n` is your sentinel value, you could do something like this:

1. Load the `inputstream` into a `string` variable
2. Go character by character through the `string` variable checking to see if `\n` is in the input (you could use a `for loop` and the `substing(i, i+2)`
3. If it is found, then you could add it to an array